# MVC 5 c# foreach over ViewBag containing 3 Lists in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, viewbag

I have a UserProfileModel which contains standard profile items plus two List of classes which contain UserLanguages and UserPendingItems. I have seen a number of questions that are similar but do not help me...

**UserProfileModels**

```
public class UserProfileModels
{
    [Key]
    public string UserProfileID { get; set; } // Same as User ID
    public string UserProfilePictureURL { get; set; }
    public string UserProfileCompanyID { get; set; } // Same as Company ID
    // IF UserProfileCompanyID is empty then EU is an individual and the following fields are available
    // Else Get the information from the CompanyProfile

    public string UserProfileStreet { get; set; }
    public string UserProfileTown { get; set; }
    public string UserProfileCountry { get; set; } // Allows us to decide on currency, TimeZone, State / County, Post Code / Zip etc
    public string UserProfileState { get; set; }
    public string UserProfilePostCode { get; set; }
    public string UserProfileDOB { get; set; } // Date Of Birth
    public string UserProfileSex { get; set; }

    public string UserProfileRole { get; set; }
    // IF Role is > "Client" then the following fields are to be used.
    public string UserProfileTelephoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string UserProfileMobileNumber { get; set; }

    public List<UserLanguageModels> UserLanguages { get; set; }

    public List<UserProfilePendingItems> UserPendingItems { get; set; }

}
```

**UserProfilePendingItems**

```
public class UserProfilePendingItems
{
    public string UserProfileID { get; set; }
    public string UserProfileDescription { get; set; }
}
```

**UserLanguageModels**

```
public class UserLanguageModels
{
    public string UserProfileID { get; set; }
    public string UserLanguage { get; set; }
}
```

In the View there is a dropdown menu which contains a list of the UsersPendingItems

**View**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu extended tasks-bar">
  <div class="notify-arrow notify-arrow-green"></div>
  <li>
    <p class="green">@ViewBag.PendingMessages.Count()</p>
  </li>
```

**PROBLEMS BEGIN HERE**

```
@foreach (CCSLABS.Controllers.Administration.AdministrationController.UserProfile Message in ViewBag.PendingMessages)
{                       
  <li>
    <a href="index.html#">
      <div class="task-info">
        <div class="desc">@Message.UserPendingItems.</div>
        <div class="percent">40%</div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress progress-striped">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
         <span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
}
```

So the idea is within the User's profile we have a list of items that they need to do (Pending Items). Which we send to the View via the ViewBag (**There is probably a much better way of doing this!**) We Foreach over the ViewBag and create the dropdown menu.

However,

1. I am going to end up with too much code logic in the view making it a nightmare to maintain.
2. I can't **see** the PendingItemsModel within the ViewBag anyway.

**Questions**

1. How can I send ONLY the first 4 or 5 PendingItems, that the user has, to the View
2. How do I create the Iteration of the View List Items to generate the drop down menu using as little code in the view as possible.

Comment: I'm totally confused. You `foreach` loop uses typeof `UserProfile` but you haven't posted the model for that (and does it have a property named `UserPendingItems`)? If the model in the view is `UserProfileModels` which contains property `List<UserProfilePendingItems> UserPendingItems`, how does that relate to whats in ViewBag? And what does `<a href="index.html#">` do?

Comment: @StephenMuecke UserProfile is the var for UserProfileModels. The ViewBag.PendingUserItems = UserProfile, so contains the contents of the UserProfileModels. The <a href - does nothing at the moment.

Comment: `@foreach(UserProfile Message in ViewBag.PendingMessages)` means you have a class named `UserProfile` and that `ViewBag.PendingMessages` is  typeof `IEnumerable<UserProfile>` What is `UserProfile`? You havn't posted it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke USerProfile is the name I instantiated UserProfileModels with.

Comment: What do you mean its the name? If you don't have a class `UserProfile` this wont even compile.

Comment: @StephenMuecke The class being instantiated is UserProfileModels and is instantiated like all classes like this. UserProfileModels UserProfile = new UserProfileModels();

Comment: That bits fine. But `@foreach(UserProfile Message in ViewBag.PendingMessages)` is not. If you put that piece of code in your project you would get an error saying _The type or namespace "UserProfile" could not be found..._. I suggest you study the usage of the `foreach` statement. Perhaps you mean something like `foreach(UserProfilePendingItems item in UserProfile.UserPendingItems)` which will loop through each `UserProfilePendingItems` object in the `UserPendingItems` property of an instance of `UserProfileModels`